# Can't start docker engine on window 2019

Tags: docker, windows-server, docker-for-windows, windows-server-2019

I am starting with docker. To setup the environment on a windows 2019 server to run Linux containers i follow [this](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-docker-containers-on-windows-server-2019/) procedure.

The problems start at step:

```
  Get-VM WinContainerHost | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

that throw the error

```
Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "WinContainerHost".
```

I checked hyper-v and there was no vm, so i continued.

The engine does not start.
When i try to start it using

```
Net start docker
```

it ends unexpectedly

The `eventlog` was 3 warnings but all from unregistered sources, so i can't see the actual errors.

First one is:

> The description for Event ID 1 from source docker cannot be found.
>   Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your
>   local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or
>   repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Running experimental build

The problem may come from behind because i did some experiences with docker while try to setting up an working environment, like turn swarm mode on, or create services and networks while was on windows containers mode.